# continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} x\sin\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0\\ 0 & \text{if } x=0\end{array}\right.$$
Show that this function is continuous at $x=0$.

so the left side limit is $0$ and the function itself is $0$ and $x=0$. However the right sided limit is undefined at $0$.

How do you show it is continuous when the right sides limit is undefined?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} |g(x)| =\lim_{x\to 0}  |x\sin(\cos x/x)|\leq \lim_{x\to 0} |x|$$
since $\sin$ does not exceed 1 in absolute value...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$|g(x)|\leq|x|$ for every $x$

.......

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, even though $\frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ goes to infinity as $x$ goes to $0$, the function $\sin$ is always bounded between $-1$ and $1$, so as $x$ goes to $0$, $x \sin\Big( \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \Big)$ is between $-x$ and $x$, hence tends to $0$ for the sandwitch rule.